# How to change values in element.style python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

[image: value i want to change]

The webpage is [the following](http://m.11st.co.kr/products/m/2455871347?prdNo=2455871347).

It has to go on mobile. I want to change the value of `'animation-duration'` under
id `'optionContainer'`.

It seems like it's attached to the website or something

I tried:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('optionContainer').style.animated.animation-duration = '.05s';")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I could not find `optionContainer` id at all in the page.

Comment: It has to be on mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple. Write `animationDuration` instead of `animation-duration`, that would raise a syntax error in Javascript.
And also better get the element directly by its class.

```
 driver.execute_script("document.getElementByClassName('animated').style.animationDuration = '.05s';")
```

Comment: it worked!  but i had change a little bit i had to use id name still thx